# Problem installing Pycaret in Google Colab

Tags: python, pycaret

I am trying to install `pycaret` in Google Colab and I am getting this error:

```
error: **subprocess-exited-with-error**
  
× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
  
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× **Encountered error while generating package metadata.**
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I am attaching the screenshot for reference. Can anyone help me with that? Thanks in advance

I was trying `!pip install pycaret[full]` on Google Colab and this happened:

[image: link to the image below]

Comment: There is no screenshot linked in your question, and also the error is incomplete (maybe the screenshot shows it).

Comment: Please post the full log message beginning to end as text, even if it is very long. Does the installation work on your local machine? Does the installation work for a different version?

Comment: I think its availiable now.Please check once

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue.  Was able to get around it running the cell with a regular pip install twice in succession:

pip install pycaret

Comment: Ran this yesterday in Google Colab and again today.  After running pip install pycaret (not the full version).  Only other pip install I had to do was NumPy.  This is a change from previous versions where you had to do a full install in order for it to run.

Answer (score 0):

This will resolve your issues.

!pip install --pre -U pycaret

Please follow bellow thread.

https://github.com/pycaret/pycaret/issues/3150#issuecomment-1336593199